# Average excluding specific values from very large list

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, mean

I am working with a very large list (~1GB) of travel times and am trying to average them, but there is a quirk where if the trip is not possible the value is set to the highest possible integer value, which destroys the entire calculation.  The travel times are stored in a list, and the lists are in a dictionary.

From point A to B and B to C would look like:

```
{'AB':[3,5,10],'BC':[2,3,5,10,2147483647]}
```

The average between AB should be 6 and BC should be 5 (not 429496733.4).

How can I exclude rogue values from the average calculation?

Comment: With large lists, consider using numpy arrays. You can turn that into a masked array, masking values above a limit, then using `np.nanmean`. Alternatively, calculate the median instead of the mean (with or without numpy, with or without masked values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module provides a [`mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) function which can take an iterator as input, so you don't have to make a copy of the list to filter out the values you want to discard.

Here's a mocked up example of your data, where 90% of the 1 million elements are in the range 1 to 9 inclusive, and 10% are your rogue value:

```
from random import randint, random

data = [randint(1, 9) if random() < 0.9 else 2147483647 for _ in range(1000000)]
```

Here's how to use `statistics.mean()` to get the mean **including** rogue values:

```
>>> from statistics import mean

>>> mean(data)
215405499.193486
```

… and here's how to do so iterating over it **excluding** rogue values:

```
>>> mean(x for x in data if x != 2147483647)
4.998926301609214
```

Wrapping that up in a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> travel_times = {'AB':[3,5,10],'BC':[2,3,5,10,2147483647]}
>>> {k: mean(x for x in v if x != 2147483647) for k, v in travel_times.items()}
{'BC': 5, 'AB': 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per user707650's comment above, here is a solution that utilizes `numpy` and converts each list to a masked array before computing the mean:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> travel_times = {'AB':[3,5,10],'BC':[2,3,5,10,2147483647]}

>>> {k: np.nanmean(np.ma.MaskedArray(v, mask=(np.array(v) == 2147483647))) 
   for k, v in travel_times.items()}

{'AB': 6.0, 'BC': 5.0}
```

Using the example of a large list from @zero-piraeus's answer, we can see the difference in execution times:

```
from random import randint, random
from statistics import mean
import numpy as np

data = [randint(1, 9) if random() < 0.9 else 2147483647 for _ in range(1000000)]
```

```
>>> %timeit mean(x for x in data if x != 2147483647)
1 loop, best of 3: 531 ms per loop

>>> %timeit np.nanmean(np.ma.MaskedArray(data, mask=(np.array(data) == 2147483647)))
10 loops, best of 3: 160 ms per loop
```